# How to make a Global variable and throw values into it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-2.3

I'm just new to android studio and I have this problem.
I have 3 different tabs with different fragments and i have checkboxes on it. I used comomunicator to set value for the floating Fragment. But everytime I change tab and select a checkbox in the other tab. The Value of the 1st tab will not count anymore and It will start to zero, so I plan to make a Global variable instead of a local variable in that fragment because in java i use global variable for efficiency. So my question is How can I make a Global variable and store all the values to it.

heres my Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    CheckBox mc1,mc2,mc3,mc4,mc5,mc6,mc7,mc8,mc9,mc10,mc11,mc12;
    communicator comm;
    int total;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        mc1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc1);
        mc1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc2);
        mc2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc3);
        mc3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc4=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc4);
        mc4.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc5=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc5);
        mc5.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc6=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc6);
        mc6.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc7=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc7);
        mc7.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc8=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc8);
        mc8.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc9=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc9);
        mc9.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc10=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc10);
        mc10.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc11=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc11);
        mc11.setOnClickListener(this);
        mc12=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mc12);
        mc12.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.mc1:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc2:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc3:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+350;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-350;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc4:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-400;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc5:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc6:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc7:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-250;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc8:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc9:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc10:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc11:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+450;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-450;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mc12:
                if(checked){
                    total=total+550;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                else{
                    total=total-550;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n"+total+" Php.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

heres my Tab2:

```
public class Tab2 extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    CheckBox aoc1,aoc2,aoc3,aoc4;
    communicator comm;
    int total;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        aoc1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc1);
        aoc1.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc2);
        aoc2.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc3);
        aoc3.setOnClickListener(this);
        aoc4=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aoc4);
        aoc4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.aoc1:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 50;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc2:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc3:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 100;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.aoc4:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 150;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

heres my Tab3:

```
public class Tab3 extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment implements  View.OnClickListener{
    CheckBox fc1,fc2,fc3,fc4,fc5,fc6,fc7,fc8;
    int total=0;
    communicator comm;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        fc1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc1);
        fc1.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc2);
        fc2.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc3);
        fc3.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc4=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc4);
        fc4.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc5=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc5);
        fc5.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc6=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc6);
        fc6.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc7=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc7);
        fc7.setOnClickListener(this);
        fc8=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fc8);
        fc8.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fc1:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 70;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 70;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc2:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 80;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 80;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc3:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 300;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 300;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc4:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 300;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 300;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc5:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 200;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc6:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 260;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 260;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc7:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 180;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 180;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fc8:
                if (checked) {
                    total = total + 180;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                } else {
                    total = total - 180;
                    comm.respond("Total:\n" + total + " Php.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
PS. I used communicator to throw values in my floating Fragment.

Comment: I believe more efficient way would be to store this variable using SharedPreferences so its value won't change everytime.

Comment: i'll try it sir thanks for suggestion.

Comment: BTW sir how can i implement sharedpreference?

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

To save value:

sharedpreferences.edit().putString("key", "value").apply();

To retrieve value:
sharedpreferences.getString("key", "default");

Answer (score 1):

Use application class. Create a class which extends Application, declare all your variables in the class and create getters and setters for the variables. You can now use the class to store and retrieve data from any fragment.

[This](https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/) link will help you get started.